# How to check if a field is editable or not using SuitScript?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

Is there any way in Netsuite to check if a field is editable or not using the SuitScript?
I need to check the fields of Support case Object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a client script you can use the `currentRecord` module.

Run this in your browser console on a case record;

```
var currentRecord;
require(['N/currentRecord'],
function (c) {
    currentRecord = c.get();
    var myField = currentRecord.getField({fieldId: 'title'});
    console.log('Disabled: ' + myField.isDisabled + ' readonly: ' + myField.isReadOnly);
});
```